# Rails 3.2.3 mysql error "max_prepared_stmt_count"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running a `Rails 3.2.3` app deployed with apache2/passenger on a virtual host with a mysql database server. I got this error after a lot of traffic was hitting the site:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Can't create more than 
max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382)
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the amount of traffic, but if so I have to find a way around this.  Anyone had this error before?  I can't figure out how to stop it.

Here's what i see in mysql:

mysql> show global status like 'com_stmt%';

| Com_stmt_close          | 1720319 
| Com_stmt_execute        | 2094137 |

| Com_stmt_fetch          | 0       |

| Com_stmt_prepare        | 1768924 |

| Com_stmt_reprepare      | 0       |

| Com_stmt_reset          | 0       |

| Com_stmt_send_long_data | 0       |

+-------------------------+---------+

I am running resque gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i'm tentatively weighing in on an answer here.  I used femtoRgon's tip to check the status.  Then i added these two lines to my database.yml file

```
  pool: 30
  prepared_statements: false
```

I restarted mysql. Now after having the app run for a while I see this:

```
mysql> show global status like 'com_stmt%';

| Com_stmt_close          | 189017 |

| Com_stmt_execute        | 189017 |

| Com_stmt_fetch          | 0      |

| Com_stmt_prepare        | 189017 |

| Com_stmt_reprepare      | 0      |

| Com_stmt_reset          | 0      |

| Com_stmt_send_long_data | 0      |
```

No discrepancies anywhere...  Plus where I USED to see this:

```
Ecard Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `ecards`.* FROM `ecards` WHERE `ecards`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "34"]]
```

I now see this:

```
Ecard Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `ecards`.* FROM `ecards` WHERE `ecards`.`id` = 34 LIMIT 1
```

I think that shows that I'm no longer using prepare statements?   Would love any thoughts - I guess I'll have to keep monitoring to see how things go...

Comment: As long as it doesn't adversely affect performance for you, I see no reason this wouldn't solve the problem.  Especially given that status you posted, it certainly seems to have done the job.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely something is opening prepared statements against the database and not closing them.

To check this, try querying:

```
show global status like ‘com_stmt%’;
```

A very large discrepancy between Com_stmt_prepare and Com_stmt_close would indicate something leaving prepared statements open.  Com_stmt_close = 0 would, of course, be particularly telling.

---

It's possible, with the relatively small discrepancy between the two, that you actually do need that many open statements at once, though I'd still consider it more likely that you are leaking them somewhere (error/edge case handling, being the classic example of where people often forget to close resources).

You can increase the number of statements allowed with:

```
set global max_prepared_stmt_count=<some_larger number>;
```

Which should get things rolling again.  Careful with too high a limit, as that can leave you vulnerable to a DoS.

After that, I'd monitor it, and see if more prepared statements are accumulated over time.

If you:

```
set global general_log = 'ON';
```

the general log will log `Prepare` statements.  Look for any without a matching Close, to help find any such issues.

Comment: Thanks, not so much of a discrepancy between the two to necessarily conclude the issue I had suspected.  I've updated with some more thoughts.

Comment: i'm getting a mysql error when doing set global_log=ON;  I don't think it's related to the issue, i just need to know how to get global logs turned on!  mysql> set global_log=ON;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'global_log'

Comment: Sorry, try:  `set global general_log = 'ON';`  Editted my answer to reflect

Comment: what do you think of my answer above?  do you think that fixes it?  how would i test?